# How do I find a preexisting variable with a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, variables, blit

How do I find a preexisting variable with a list of strings in Python?

I have a list of strings, such as:

```
letters = ["C", "A", "M", "P"]
```

and a set of preexisting variables, such as:

```
C = pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgC.png")
A = pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgA.png")
M = pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgM.png")
P = pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgP.png")
```

I am looking for a command such as:

```
surface.blit(letters[0])
```

to display the image on the screen.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyber's method has the advantage of keeping your namespace more organized, but it's also nice to know about [globals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), with which you can do this:

```
surface.blit(globals()[letters[0]])
```

(assuming `C`, `A`, `M`, `P` are defined in the global namespace. If they are local variables, you could use [vars()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) instead of `globals()`.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response unutbu. I tried using 'globals()' as you suggested and got the following error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 64, in main
    menuIcons.add((menu.icon("CAMPAIGN")))
  File "/media/PROGRAMMING/Files/Reality/menu.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.image.blit(globals()[iconComponents[0]])
KeyError: 'C'

Comment: I probably should have been more specific. My variables are in my main.py and I want to blit the images to a sprites self.image in a class built in menu.py. If you wish i can upload a full copy of my code.

Comment: There are lots of different options depending on how you've structured your code -- how `main` is imported by `menu`, or vice versa, how the function is getting called, if the variables can simply be passed as arguments, etc. For specific advice, please post your code.

Comment: Also note that Cyber's method is better, and there should be a way to incorporate that into your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go for a dictionary.

```
d = {
    'C': pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgC.png"),
    'A': pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgA.png"),
    'M': pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgM.png"),
    'P': pygame.image.load("resources/menu icons/imgP.png")
    }
```

Then you can look stuff up that way

```
d['A']
```

Or

```
d[letters[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Cyber. Unfortunately I am unable to use  a dictionary in this instance as I am using list() to create the list of strings from a single string.